# Cannot Define Object in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

All, I have a user control. In the XAML markup for this control I want to define a resource (instatiate an object called `cellColorConverter` of the class `CellColorConverter` which is defined in the same namespace as the control. I have

```
<UserControl x:Class="ResourceStudio.Resource.Resource"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" Height="331.2" Width="340">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceStudio.Resource:CellColorConverter x:Key ="cellColorConverter"/> // <- Error.
</UserControl.Resources>
```

This is giving a compile-time error saying

> The namespace prefix `ResourceStudio.Res` is not defined.

**What am I doing wrong here?**

Thanks for your time.

---

*Update: I now have*

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ResourceStudio.Resource;assembly=ResourceStudio"
             mc:Ignorable="d" Height="331.2" Width="340">
   <UserControl.Resources>
      <local:CellColorConverter x:Key ="cellColorConverter"/>
   </UserControl.Resources>
```

*The `CellColorConverter` class is in the name space `ResourceStudio.Resource`, defined as*

```
namespace ResourceStudio.Resource
{
   public class CellColorConverter : IMultiValueConverter
   {
       // ...     
   }
}
```

*I still get the following error*

> The name "CellColorConverter" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:ResourceStudio.Resource;assembly=ResourceStudio". F:\Camus\ResourceStudio\ResourceStudio\ResourceStudio\Resource\Resource.xaml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the XAML:

```
<ResourceStudio.Resource:CellColorConverter />
```

The `ResourceStudio.Resource` is an XML namespace for `CellColorConverter`.

You need to map this XML namespace to a .NET namespace:

```
<UserControl xmlns:ResourceStudio.Resource="clr-namespace:ResourceStudio.Resource;assembly=ResourceStudio" ... />
```

The actual namespace and assembly name depend upon what you've called them in your code.

[This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms747086.aspx) provides more information.

Also, you can make the namespace shorter:

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:..."

<local:CellColorConverter ... >
```

Comment: +1 Thanks very much for your time. I have changed this accordingly, but I am still getting _The name "CellColorConverter" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace=ResourceStudio.Resource;assembly=ResourceStudio"_?

Comment: There has to be a colon `:` instead of `=` following `clr-namespace`, like `clr-namespace:ResourceStudio.Resource;assembly=ResourceStudio`.

Comment: @Killercam, where do you define the `CellColorConverter` class? You have to use the namespace and assembly names for that type in the string as shown.

Comment: @DrewNoakes I have updated my question. I still get an error. Again thanks for your time here...

Comment: @Killercam, looks like you're getting close. The namespace looks correct, so probably the assembly name is incorrect. What is the name of the .dll file that contains the `CellColorConverter` class? This is probably the same name as the project in VS. Try using that name for the assembly.

Comment: @Killercam - If your `Usercontrol` and `Converter` resides in same assembly, you can omit the assembly part - `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ResourceStudio.Resource`.

Comment: @RohitVats That's entirely true, and you even *have to* omit the assembly part. It won't work otherwise.